# Smooth position changes using CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

How can I animate/smooth automatic changes in position of an element, for example when an element gets removed and other DOMs beneath it move up? Obviously using any of

```
animation: position 1s ease-out;
animation: top 1s ease-out;
transition: position 1s ease-out;
transition: top 1s ease-out;
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `transition` ?

Comment: You can't animate an element that doesn't change. You need to animate the element that *does* change, for example, the element being removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that something is going to be removed, and could be with CSS, then you can use keyframes and a CSS animations to get the effect you want.

A small demo is below.

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#one,
#two {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#one {
  top: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  animation-name: one_hide;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#two {
  top: 115px;
  background: lightgreen;
  animation-name: two_move;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes one_hide {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
  }
}
@keyframes two_move {
  from {
    top: 115px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="one">Some Text</div>
<div id="two">Second Div</div>
```

- [CSS @Keyframes - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Comment: I have considered keyframes but the problem is that I want to make it generic, i.e. it should work on a lists of different length without having to hard-code the top positions of each list element.

Comment: You may well have to look into a javascript alternative then @ScepticalJule